# Is there a way to automatically edit button's properties in Java JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, netbeans-12

I've set following properties for one of my buttons.

```
try {
    name.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(newFile("./src/main/java/resorces/Default.png"))));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
name.setBorderPainted(false); 
name.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
name.setFocusPainted(false); 
name.setOpaque(false);
```

My problem is that I have a bunch of buttons just like this one. I was wondering if it's possible to make a method that would take in button's name and set all the properties for me.

Example:

```
public void SetProperties(??? x){
    try {
        x.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(newFile("./src/main/java/resorces/Default.png"))));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    x.setBorderPainted(false); 
    x.setContentAreaFilled(false); 
    x.setFocusPainted(false); 
    x.setOpaque(false);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, the concept is known as “factory” or “builder” pattern

Comment: What is the question here?  You ask if you are able to do something, and then you go ahead and show that you can in fact do it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You could...

Use a ["builder pattern"](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

The concept is to provide a workflow which allows you to apply all the properties you want and then have that object "built", for example...

```
public class ButtonBuilder<Builder extends ButtonBuilder<Builder>> {
    private JButton button;

    public ButtonBuilder() {
        button = new JButton();
    }
    
    public Builder withText(String text) {
        button.setText(text);
        return (Builder)this;
    }
    
    public Builder withIcon(Icon icon) {
        button.setIcon(icon);
        return (Builder)this;
    }
    
    public Builder borderPainted(boolean painted) {
        button.setBorderPainted(painted);
        return (Builder)this;
    }
    
    public Builder contentAreaFilled(boolean painted) {
        button.setContentAreaFilled(painted);
        return (Builder)this;
    }
    
    public Builder focusPainted(boolean painted) {
        button.setFocusPainted(painted);
        return (Builder)this;
    }
    
    public JButton build() {
        return button;
    }
}
```

*nb: Note, a common pattern for a builder is store the properties in some kind of cache/lookup, which are then applied when you call build, but in this case, it's just easier to apply them directly to the button itself*

*nb: Obviously, I've only supplied a small subset of properties you might want to specify for a button, you'll need to add the rest ;)*

And then you can build the button using something like...

```
JButton happyButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .withText("Happy")
        .withIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/happy.png"))))
        .borderPainted(false)
        .focusPainted(false)
        .contentAreaFilled(false)
        .build();
```

> But that's not what I asked, I don't want to have to have reapply the all the properties each time I want to create a button

Yes, I know, I was getting to it.  Once you have a "base" builder, you could make one or more "custom" extensions, which could apply default values directly, for example...

```
public class MyCustomButtonBuilder extends ButtonBuilder<MyCustomButtonBuilder> {
    public MyCustomButtonBuilder(String text) {
        this(text, null);
    }
    
    public MyCustomButtonBuilder(Icon icon) {
        this(null, icon);
    }
    
    public MyCustomButtonBuilder(String text, Icon icon) {
        super();
        withText(text)
                .withIcon(icon)
                .borderPainted(false)
                .focusPainted(false)
                .contentAreaFilled(false);
    }
}
```

which could then be used something like...

```
JButton sadButton = new MyCustomButtonBuilder("Sad", new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Sad.png"))))
        .build();
```

## You could...

Use a ["factory pattern"](https://www.javatpoint.com/factory-method-design-pattern#:%7E:text=A%20Factory%20Pattern%20or%20Factory,the%20instance%20of%20the%20class.), for example...

```
public class ButtonFactory {
    public static JButton makePlainButton() {
        return makePlainButton(null, null);
    }

    public static JButton makePlainButton(String text) {
        return makePlainButton(text, null);
    }

    public static JButton makePlainButton(String text, Icon icon) {
        JButton btn = new JButton(text, icon);
        btn.setBorderPainted(false);
        btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.setOpaque(false);
        return btn;
    }
}
```

which could be used something like...

```
JButton heartButton = ButtonFactory.makePlainButton(
        "Heart", 
        new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Heart.png")))
);
```

The factory pattern could allow you to supply a multiple number of different types of buttons, configured different based on your common needs.

## You could...

Combine the two concepts, for example...

```
public class ButtonFactory {
    public static JButton makePlainButton() {
        return makePlainButton(null, null);
    }

    public static JButton makePlainButton(String text) {
        return makePlainButton(text, null);
    }

    public static JButton makePlainButton(String text, Icon icon) {
        return new ButtonBuilder()
                .withText(text)
                .withIcon(icon)
                .borderPainted(false)
                .focusPainted(false)
                .contentAreaFilled(false)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look out I helped someone - in what ways does this not answer the question? In what was can this be improved? Since no other answer has been provided I can only assume you don’t understand the question/answer or have a personal gripe with me offering assistance

Comment: Thanks for help! Everything was explained in a clear and simple way. I'll now try to implement this into my project. Thanks again!